Finalizacion de proyecto en Python con Django y sqlite
necesito ayuda con la parte final de mi proyecto. En la parte cuando quiero que aparezca el resultado de mi busqueda los campos quedan vacios y no se como solucionarlo. Agradezco cualquier ayuda
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block titulo %}Resultados{% endblock %}

{% block cabecera %}Resultados de su busqueda{% endblock %}

{% block contenido %}

{% if viajes %}
    {% for viaje in viajes %}
        <p>Destino: {{viajes.Destino}}</p>
        <p>Precio: {{viajes.Precio}}</p>
        <p>Tipo: {{viajes.Tipo}}</p>
        <img src="{{viajes.fotos.url}}" alt="" width="200">
        
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>Su busqueda no ha dado resultados</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}


Fijate que en el for estás haciendo viajes.Destino, viajes.Precio, etc. Estás referenciando a la lista de elementos, en lugar del elemento en sí.
En el foreach a cada elemento sobre el que estás iterando lo declaraste viaje, deberías reemplazarlo por viaje.Destino, viaje.Precio, etc.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
